# Is there a method to make the linerenderer get specific positions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I did the program to generate a line using linerenderer onmouse click and drag to create a flowfree like game,but the problem is the linerenderer is adding positions infinitely as it is in the update block and i want to record only the grid positions.and i want the line to get attached to the positions on drag.

```
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero, Mathf.Infinity);
        if (hit.collider != null && hit.collider.tag == "Dot")
        {
            isDragging = true;
            line.positionCount = dragCount ;
            line.SetPosition(0, hit.collider.transform.position);
        }
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && isDragging)
    {
        Vector3 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        mousePosition.z = 0f;


        foreach (Vector3 target in pos)
        {
            if (Vector3.Distance(mousePosition, target) < 0.5f)
            {
                line.positionCount = dragCount;
                line.SetPosition(dragCount - 1, target);
                dragCount = dragCount + 1;
                print(dragCount);
                endPoint = target;
            }
        }

        line.SetPosition(dragCount - 1, mousePosition);
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && isDragging)
    {
        isDragging = false;
        if (line.positionCount <= 2)
        {

            line.positionCount = 0;
        }
    }
```

This is the program i did.I was expecting to get the grid positions but it is not working the linerenderer is keep on recording positions infinitely.

Comment: `if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && isDragging)` will be true each and every frame and in there you do `dragCount = dragCount + 1;` then with the next `GetMouseButtonDown` you do `line.positionCount = dragCount ;`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion,but i want to draw a line when I click and drag the mouse along the grid.